# Can Java 8 implement interface on the fly for method reference?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference, constructor-reference

I learn new features of Java 8.

I am playing with different examples and I have found a strange behaviour:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {       
    method(Test::new);
}
static class Test{
}

private static void method(Supplier<Test> testSupplier){
    Test test = testSupplier.get();
}
```

This code compiles successfully but I have no idea how it works.

Why is `Test::new` acceptable as Supplier?

Supplier interface looks very simple:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Supplier<T> {    
    T get();
}
```

Comment: For dynamically implementing which sort of happens AFAIK there is this beast: [`java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html)

Comment: Note that an "empty" class declaration, such as for your `class Test`, implicitly has a no-arg constructor. That's why you can write `new Test()` and have it work, any why a lambda or method reference to this constructor works.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis maybe first comment to linked question is more relevant

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) interface has a single (functional) method that:

- does not take any parameters;
- returns an object.

Therefore, any method that comply with those two points, comply with the functional contract of `Supplier` (because the methods will have the same signature).

Here, the method in question is a method reference. It takes no parameters and returns a new instance of `Test`. You could rewrite it to:

```
method(() -> new Test());
```

`Test::new` in syntactic sugar for this lambda expression.

Comment: Thus if answer the question from my subject - Yes, method reference was invented for dynamically interface implementation.

Answer (score 11):

`Test::new` is a method reference. Rather than adding a new explanation it's worth taking a look at the tutorial for [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) as it explains them pretty well.

The direct answer to your question is that `Supplier` is a functional interface - meaning that it has a single non-default method. The constructor for `Test` has exactly the same signature (no arguments, returns `Test`) and so can be directly referenced to create an anonymous `Supplier`.

There are four flavours of method references: check out the tutorial to understand them all.

Comment: Thus this feature allow that old classes can implement newly created interface. WoW!

Comment: @gstackoverflow Yes that's correct. As long as the signatures match you can refer to the method to create an instance of the interface. When used well it can substantially improve the readability of code.

Answer (score 3):

It might be a `Function`, rather than a supplier, if an argument is required. But method references can refer to constructors in the same way they refer to methods; they just have a funny name (`new`).

From [the Java Tutorial,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) there are four kinds of method references:

```
Kind                              Example
-------------------------------   ------------------------------------
Reference to a static method      ContainingClass::staticMethodName
Reference to an instance method   containingObject::instanceMethodName
of a particular object  
Reference to an instance method   ContainingType::methodName
of an arbitrary object of a 
particular type
Reference to a constructor        ClassName::new
```